# Official source of Jasper JSP Engine JAR file

Tags: apache, jsp, maven, jar

I'm including the class org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet in my Java project to compile JSP files at run-time (this project is based around an embedded Jetty implementation).  The class seems to be part of the Jetty JSP Engine which seems to be included in Tomcat and Glassfish.  The question I have is what is the official source for the JAR files that include this class?

The best source I've found so far is the Maven repositories, however, I'm assuming the there is an official Jasper project somewhere on the web that creates the original JAR files ... after all where do the Maven repos get this file from?  I just want to make sure I'm getting the latest and greatest version of the class since there seem to be many versions floating around the web with lots of repositories missing stuff or having file versions that others don't.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for the same thing and the closest thing I found was the Tomcat source code repository.

Here is the folder used for Tomcat v7.0.x

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/jasper/

You can find other versions here

http://tomcat.apache.org/svn.html

This would explain why some maven repositories package Jasper in a folder such as

%repository%/org.apache.tomcat/jasper

Answer (score 1):

There is no Jasper project, other than what is maintained in the Tomcat Project. The source can be found at svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/  All apache projects are listed on apache.org, and Jasper is an apache product, but it is under the Tomcat umbrella.